# Ignore element inside only certain divs

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have a basic web scraper written which pulls short sections of text from a webpage and puts them into a list. My problem is that there are dynamic ads that appear on the page and mess up the lists. 
The page I'm scraping is a Yelp restaurant listing page.

I pull out the biz-name (business name) and add it to the list and it works fine but when the ads appear the scraper pulls the biz-name also.

This is the structure but I can't figure out how to ignore the 'AD element' and just scrape the normal business names. I've cut it down a lot and removed the 'unimportant' elements.

This is with an AD:

```
<li class="yloca-search-result">
   ...
      ... 
         <a class="biz-name"...><span>San Lorenzo’s</span></a>
</li>
```

This is a normal listing:

```
<li class="regular-search-result">
   ...
      ...
         <a class="biz-name"...><span>BigGrill</span></a>
</li>
```

I've been trying to make Nokogiri ignore the business name inside the `<li class="yloca-search-result">` and only select the others inside the `regular-search-result` class.
I can't figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction at least? Is it possible?

Comment: You do know that Yelp has an [API](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview) designed to help you avoid scraping pages? I'd recommend taking advantage of it.

Comment: @theTinMan I tried it but it doesn't give the same results and it's limited to a number of results. It's obviously much easier to use but scraping was giving me better results.

Comment: Be aware that their TOS probably bans scraping so you run a good risk of being banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Wasn't difficult but I just couldn't see the answer.

```
ad = doc3.at_css("li.yloca-search-result")
ad.remove
```

Comment: You probably want to use `doc3.search('li.yloca-search-result').unlink`. That will remove all ads from the page in a single pass.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you!